# Cycling through different ranges to copy while looping

Tags: vba, excel

This is my current code.

```
Sub Loops()

    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim output As Variant
    Dim outputRange(1 To 3) As Range

    Set outputRange(1) = Worksheets("vbaTest").Range("output1", Worksheets("vbaTest").Range("output1").End(xlDown))
    Set outputRange(2) = Worksheets("vbaTest").Range("output2", Worksheets("vbaTest").Range("output2").End(xlDown))
    Set outputRange(3) = Worksheets("vbaTest").Range("output3", Worksheets("vbaTest").Range("output3").End(xlDown))

For Each output In outputRange

    'The path and file names:
    MyPath = "C:\Users\x\Custom Office Templates"
    MyFileName = "Test"
    'Makes sure the path name ends with "\":
    If Not Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    'Makes sure the filename ends with ".csv"
    If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".txt" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".txt"
    'Copies the sheet to a new workbook:
    Sheets("vbaTest").Range("**output1**").Copy
    'The new workbook becomes Activeworkbook:
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveSheet.Columns("A").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End With

'Brings back original sheet
Workbooks("vbaTest.csv").Activate
'Starts at the top of code
Next output

End Sub
```

I'm having trouble looping through the different ranges I've set when it comes to output1. "Sheets("vbaTest").Range("**output1**").Copy"

I'm trying to get vba to loop through the three other outputs that I've set. Any suggestions?

Comment: You want that part to change to the different output ranges, correct? Wouldn't `Sheets("vbaTest").Range(output.address).Copy` work?

Comment: Yes. It just worked. I started VBA yesterday, and I've been stuck on that one point for hours and hours.

Thank you so much!

Comment: just use `output.Copy`, since output is _already_ a `Range` (though through `Variant` _lens_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could shorten down to:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Loops()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFileName As String
    Dim output As Variant
    Dim outputRange(1 To 3) As Range


    With Worksheets("vbaTest") '<--| reference your worksheet once and for all!
        Set outputRange(1) = .Range("output1", .Range("output1").End(xlDown)) '<--| all "dotted" reference implicitly assume the object after preceeding 'With' keyword as the parent one
        Set outputRange(2) = .Range("output2", .Range("output2").End(xlDown))
        Set outputRange(3) = .Range("output3", .Range("output3").End(xlDown))
    End With

    For Each output In outputRange
        Workbooks.Add.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(output.Rows.Count).Value = output.Value
    Next output

' the following code doesn't currently depend on looping variable
' so I put it outside the loop-> I guess you're setting the new workbooks names

    'The path and file names:
    MyPath = "C:\Users\x\Custom Office Templates"
    MyFileName = "Test"
    'Makes sure the path name ends with "\":
    If Not Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    'Makes sure the filename ends with ".csv"
    If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".txt" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".txt"


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes a lot of sense.

What's the best way to save the files separately at that point?

So far, all I have is the code below, but it's not working for some reason. I would include this before I end the sub. 

.SaveAs Filename:= _
            MyPath & MyFileName, _
            FileFormat:=xlText, _
            CreateBackup:=False

Comment: @MRI look into the [SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) method for VBA.

Comment: @BruceWayne, it's not working unfortunately. Trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few posts on this site to do with avoiding `Select`, and if you only need the values then `Copy/Paste` can be avoided too. It might be worth reading them to assist in the efficiency of your programming.

In terms of your loop, it might be easier to iterate the indexes of your array with a `For i = 1 to n` style loop. This enables you to reference your objects as a `Range` rather than the `Variant` required in the `For Each ...` style loop.

All together, the loop element of your code could be simplified to:

```
'Add these declarations
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim i As Long

For i = LBound(outputs) To UBound(outputs)
    '...
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") _
        .Resize(outputs(i).Rows.Count, outputs(i).Columns.Count) _
        .Value = outputs(i).Value2
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional changes, you should just change that line to `Sheets("vbaTest").Range(output.address).Copy`.

However, notice how you use `.Copy`, then paste special values? Instead, we can set the two ranges equal. Also, you should use workbook/worksheet variables, to keep those straight.

Here's a slightly tweaked code:

```
Sub Loops()

    Dim MyPath As String, MyFileName As String
    Dim output As Variant
    Dim outputRange(1 To 3) As Range
    Dim newWB As Workbook
    Dim newWS As Worksheet, mainWS As Worksheet

    Set mainWS = Worksheets("vbaTest")

    With mainWS
        Set outputRange(1) = .Range("output1", .Range("output1").End(xlDown))
        Set outputRange(2) = .Range("output2", .Range("output2").End(xlDown))
        Set outputRange(3) = .Range("output3", .Range("output3").End(xlDown))
    End With

For Each output In outputRange
    Debug.Print output.Address
    'The path and file names:
    MyPath = "C:\Users\x\Custom Office Templates"
    MyFileName = "Test"
    'Makes sure the path name ends with "\":
    If Not Right(MyPath, 1) = "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    'Makes sure the filename ends with ".csv"
    If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".txt" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".txt"

    'The new workbook becomes Activeworkbook:
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    Set newWS = newWB.ActiveSheet

    'Instead of .Copy/.PasteSpecial Values (meaning, you just want the text), we can
    ' skip the clipboard completely and just set the two ranges equal to eachother:
    ' Range([destination]).Value = Range([copy range]).Value
    newWS.Columns("A").Value = mainWS.Range(output.Address).Value
    With newWB
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

'Brings back original sheet
mainWS.Activate
'Starts at the top of code
Next output

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, but if I run that code, it gives me #N/A after the values, which I'm not looking for specifically.

But I'm looking for it to copy the named ranges instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I've received from a user above that works the way I want it to is below:

Sheets("vbaTest").Range(output.address).Copy